# Slow app performance under iOS 8 simulator with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator

After upgraded to xcode 6 I found that when I run my app under iOS 8 in iOS simulator, it ran very slowly, no matter when I choose iPhone or iPad. But if I choose it to run under iOS 7 it ran  normally. 
I was thinking that it was an app/coding related problem so then I tried to deploy it on my ipad with iOS8 and strangely the app run normally, not as slow as simulator does
Does anybody on SO experience this issue?

Comment: Absolutely, I am facing this too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance in the iOS Simulator is not expected to match performance on device.  The iOS Simulator is meant as a tool for rapid prototyping and fast iteration.  Performance tuning needs to be done on real devices.

Processes running in the iOS Simulator are basically OS X processes running in a specially crafted runtime within a special bootstrap to behave like iOS rather than OS X.  Over the past 4 years, this has evolved from basically  UIKit and similar iOS Frameworks built on top of OS X Frameworks to now having our own bootstrap server (as of iOS 7), our own dyld (as of iOS 8), and only sharing the host kernel and very low level system libraries (libSystem as of iOS 7, and just the pthreads, syscalls, and platform children of libSystem as of iOS 8).

When you test an app on a device that is not currently booted, we shutdown the device and boot the new one, and that process can take 10s to a minute or 2 to complete based primarily on your disk's I/O bandwidth and what other tasks on your system are demanding of it.

If you see major performance issues with a sim device that has been booted for a while and don't have any obvious background tasks running (compilation, rsync, whatever), take a sysdiagnose and take a look at the simulator processes in the spin dump and fs_usage to see what's likely going on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Using the simulator has become painfully slow since iOS 8/Xcode 6 on my Late 2009 iMac (yes, yes, time to to upgrade, I know). In fact, I've switched to using devices practically for all cases except when I need something specific from the simulator.

Comment: As the boot process is primarily I/O bound, it might be a worthwhile investment to swap out your HDD for an SSD (especially given the sales that have been happening for Black Friday / CyberWeek).  I've done that, and it's made a world of difference.

Comment: Performance on an iOS simulator should be much **faster** than on a device.  Your computer is vastly more powerful than your iPhone.  This answer doesn't really explain why this tool, which used to be fast (and a competitive advantage over other mobile platforms) has become so awfully slow recently.  It shouldn't require an SSD to run a Hello World program promptly.

Comment: Your CPU is more powerful in the sim, but graphics performance is lower due to lack of GPU, and I/O prrformance can be worse as well given that you share the (possibly smaller) pipe with the rest of your desktop.

Comment: Also, your "Hello World" app still requires the entire OS to boot first.  Once booted, it should be quite responsive.

Comment: I agree with Nate. I understand that the iOS simulator has now more stuff to load since Apple added many new frameworks. But ensuring sim runs at least similar speed as when they ran on XCode 1 is what Apple should try to do. Not just let it lag more and more as XCode version goes up. Steve Jobs wouldn't have this crap if he's still alive. RIP Steve. RIP Apple.

Comment: @Rocotilos Xcode 1 did not support iOS.  This issue doesn't have to do with supporting additional frameworks, and the issue is not the *simulator* itself.  The simulator is just an app and framework that knows how to control the simulated devices.  The simulated device is running iOS.  As iOS has gotten more complex, boot times have increased.  Yes, it is an important goal to improve responsiveness and decrease boot time, but you can't possibly expect the same boot time with iOS 9 as you can with iOS 5 on the same hardware.

Comment: I'm just saying, if Apple keeps this up, iOS simulator will soon become Android simulator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keeps this up"?  What is the issue that you are complaining about?  The iOS Simulator and Android Simulator are two completely different beasts with different design paradigms.  What exactly is the boot time of a simulated device on your system?  It boots in about 5-10 seconds on my system, and that seems like a perfectly reasonable time for booting an entire device.

Comment: You don't see a problem with having iP6+ simulator that is useless in testing Spritekit games? Can't even capture screenshot from it. Might as well delete the ip6+ sim then. Whoop dee doo.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure 'slow animations' is not selected under the Debug tab in the iOS Simulator.  That fixed the issue for me.  It might have been turned on by accident.

Comment: Fixed mine too! thanks! i've never think of it... It must be enabled by accidentally in my case...

Comment: I've spent a day trying to debug this. Apparently I had "Slow animations" turned on. FML

Answer (score 10):

If you hit ⌘T while your simulator is selected it will turn on 'slow animations' which puts everything in slow motion.  ⌘T is often used to open up a new browser tab, so just be sure your browser is selected and not your simulator.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Slow Animations make things very difficult to do, turn them off and your life gets infinitely better. ;)

Comment: Spot on. This made every animated popup much more responsive!

Answer (score 0):

Performance simulation and device different things. I think you should not pay attention to it. This error can optimize apple