# How to speed up the iPhone simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, performance, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 7.2. When I build/run my app on device, all objects and images move according to the speed I set in the code, everything moves quickly. However, on iPhone simulator in Xcode, everything moves slowly. I don't have iPhone 6Plus device so with the slow moving app in simulator it'll be difficult for me to determine whether the objects are moving fast enough in the code.

Is there a way on Xcode to make the simulator move the objects and images at the same speed as the device instead of a slowed down version?

Answer (score 14):

In the Debug menu in the Simulator, there is a "Slow Animations" menu item.  It sounds like you have it set.

Answer (score 4):

Once you execute your app in simulator you can go to Debug Menu and select the "slow Animations" option Check for slowness and UnCheck for Fast response on the screen changes.

Debug -> Slow Animation

Command + T is the short cut for same.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions:

1. -In the border of simulator with drag and make lower size, make your simulator  more faster
2. -In "Debug" allow slow Animations"
3. -In the Debug, Graphics Quality  make "Low Quality"

and the best solution a below:
quit all emulators
Run the commands on terminal

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```

then

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3
```

here are parameters

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint X
```

Where X is:

0 = auto

1 = Metal

2 = OpenCL

3 = OpenGL

[guide](https://ericasadun.com/2018/06/20/simulators-gone-bad/)

Comment: Will the `defaults` command increase speed if one isn't experiencing the problem described in the post?

Comment: That's gold. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152919/slow-app-performance-under-ios-8-simulator-with-xcode-6)

A couple things you could do include:

- Close unused applications to free system resources such as cpu & memory
- make sure "slow animations" is not selected in the simulator debug menu. Short cut for this is ⌘T
  [simulator -> Debug -> slow animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mwcp.png)

The IOS simulator is used for rapid prototyping and is not guaranteed to perform like a real device. It operates similar to any OSX application and is limited to the available resources(e.g memory, storage , cpu, etc) provided by OSX.

Comment: I was looking for "slow animations" under the Xcode debug menu. Thanks for the image link.

Comment: I'm happy you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers, in the Simulator "Debug" menu, make sure "Slow Animations" is turned off and any unnecessary applications are closed. However, if you are still having slow performance from the Simulator, you can also select "Low Image Quality" in the "Debug" menu. It's not ideal, however if your computer is still struggling to run the Simulator, it's a quick way to ensure your animations are running how they're supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the selection of the iPhone 6 instead of the iPhone X for example (less recent iPhone) makes things much faster.

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator type <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) to turn off simulator slow animation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Siri in the simulator this will make the simulator device run faster